# Show MsgBox upon receiving email with specified subject or sender

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

How do I show a MsgBox or alert upon receiving a message with a specified subject or sender?

I put this procedure in `ThisOutlookSession` block.

```
Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim myMail As MailItem
    Dim name As String

    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Set myMail = Item
        If myMail.Subject Like "*Hello world*" And myMail.Categories = "" Then
            MsgBox "Message", vbInformation, "approved"
            MailDate = myMail.ReceivedTime
            myMail.Categories = "CZEART"
            myMail.MarkAsTask (olMarkNoDate)
            myMail.Save
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So how exactly is this code not working? Have you tried [debugging](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) it?

Comment: Yes project is compiled. I send email and this and this procedure not performed. I haven't msgbox...

Comment: text comparision is case-sensitive. Try something like this for subject: `If UCase(myMail.Subject) Like "*HELLO WORLD*"` ...

Comment: Where did you put your breakpoint when you debugged? What line do you get to? "*Procedure not performed*" Really? Not executed at all? Or is it just that one of the `If` statements doesn't act as expected? Please don't make us guess. Write all that in your question.

Comment: Jean, I have a procedure that runs in the background. The procedure checks sent in the mail or an attachment. I added another, which checks the mail and should set the category. Unfortunately does not work. Sending test emails to a defined box and nothing. As if she were invisible. I'm a beginner and do not know exactly how to describe the problem. I need a message box after the mail about a specific topic. Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the code, open a mailitem with the required conditions then step through this.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()
    Dim currItem As MailItem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    olInboxItems_ItemAdd currItem
End Sub
```

Likely though you need this in the ThisOutlookSession module.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  ' instantiate objects declared WithEvents
  Set olInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62